# Pass subdomain using IIS Url rewrite and ARR

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, arr

I'm using a reverse proxy setup with AAR 3 and URL Rewrite 2.0 to change domains as follow:

App.mydomain.com/ -> localhost:8000/
Usersubdomain.mydomain.com -> localhost:8000/

Based on the subdomain I need to apply special behavior to the site (custom branding,  show hide features, etc)

Using AAR/URL Rewrite can I pass the original url or original subdomain to the localhost server via query string or header?

App.mydomain.com -> localhost:8000?originalurl=app.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match any domain in a rule condition and reference that in the action. In below rule {C:0} matches the domain:

```
<rule name="Pass domain" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:8000?originalurl={C:0}" />
</rule>
```